# BULK insert parameterize FIRSTROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Is there any way to parameterize the FIRSTROW in BULK INSERT QUERY

this is my select statement 
`SELECT TOP 1 mid from movie_titles ORDER BY mid DESC`

which return the integer value and i want to provide its result in  bulk insert statement

```
BULK
INSERT movie_titles
FROM 'A:\Netflix\movie_titles.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 'here i want to provide the result of above select query',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Having you tried using a variable, such as `FIRSTROW = @MID`?

Comment: it prompting the error "incorrect syntax near @Mid, expected INT,TEXT, STRING

Comment: BULK INSERT Into a staging table in Sql Server and from there fire an after insert trigger to do what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to provide @variable name for FIRSTROW. If you want to do so, you need to create your BULK INSERT statement dynamically via string concatenation and execute it with EXEC or sp_execute.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't directly pass parameter to `FIRSTROW`. rather you can execute `BULK INSERT` as dynamic SQL like below (***Not tested*** though but that will get you started)

```
DECLARE @midvar INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @midvar = cast(mid as INT) from movie_titles ORDER BY mid DESC;
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000);
SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT movie_titles
FROM ''A:\Netflix\movie_titles.txt'' 
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+'' +
'FIELDTERMINATOR ='',''
FIRSTROW = ' + CAST(@midvar AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')';
EXEC(@bulk_cmd);
```

Comment: it giving me this error 
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP 1 mid from movie_titles ORDER BY mid DESC;' to data type int.

Comment: @SalmanHasni, check edited answer.  I thought `mid` is int type since `firstrow` property expects int type.

Comment: How do you protect against SQL Injection?

Comment: @Rahul I've just stumbled across this answer and fixed it :) To Jimbo: there's no chance of SQL injection here because it's only a number converted to string, it's not an arbitrary user-provided string.